# error: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://myRoute. Exchange[]

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I start learning about camel and I am trying to do a simple code with java spring boot.
this is my code:

```
package camel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Configuration;
import org.apache.camel.Consume;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@Configuration
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {

     @Autowired
        private CamelContext camelContext;

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:myRoute")
//              from("timer:myTimer?period=5000")
                .setBody().constant("Hello, world!")
                .to("log:output");
            
        }
                


        @Bean
        public ProducerTemplate producerTemplate() {
            return camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        }


    
}
```

controller:

```
     @Autowired
        private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String sayHello() {
            producerTemplate.start();
            producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:myRoute", "Hello from REST API!");
            return "Message sent to Camel route";
        }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

when I am trying to send a get request, I am getting failure with status 500 with this error: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://myRoute. Exchange[]
does someone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be, that you mix Camel and Spring annotations.
Try to use `@Configuration` from spring `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration` instead of `import org.apache.camel.Configuration`.

And in general I'd recommend to separate Spring config from Camel route config. If you are using springboot and `camel-spring-boot-starter` then you can skip

```java
        @Bean
        public ProducerTemplate producerTemplate() {
            return camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        }
```

as Spring will do it for you.
Just make your class like:

```java
@Component  // from org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:myRoute")
                .setBody().constant("Hello, world!")
                .to("log:output");
        }
      
}
```

also take a careful look on package versions you are using

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>camel</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.21.0</camel.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.14</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Camel BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

For camel 3 (3.20) - use springboot 2 (2.7.14).
If you want to change to camel 4.0.0, you can switch to springboot 3 and Java 17

Answer (score 1):

I added this:

`@Configuration @ComponentScan("camel")`

to the controller and now it works!
tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it to be:

```
package camel;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


    @Component 
    public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    
               @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:myRoute")
                    .setBody().constant("Hello, world!")
                    .to("log:output");
                }
 but still the same error :(
```

Comment: added also the pom.xml content, plese check that out - especially package versions